# WEKA classifyinstance and distributionforinstance methods

Tags: java, machine-learning, data-mining, weka

In WEKA, when I try to debug the code with an instance that has to be classified with a trained model using SVM, I see that first I get into classifyInstance() to classify a test instance, and then this method calls distributionforinstance() method. There, inside the distributionforinstance() method, I see that we make a call back to classifyinstance() method.

Isn't this a chicken-egg kind of problem where these two methods are calling back each other?
What is happening out here?

Comment: At the time I wrote a classifier, everything was OK. Mind those are abstract methods and You're suppose to override one of them in a implementation. If your classifier returns a distribution, then WEKA can use the classifyInstance method from superclass to select only the best based on distribution. I might be wrong, it's been a long time since I touched on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of Rekin is correct:

If you just derived from `Classifier`, you inherited the default implementations of `classifyInstance()` and `distributionforinstance()`. You need to implement at least one of the two for it to work.

When you debug your code, it may be that the debugger somehow jumps in the abstract class `Classifier` instead of the specific SVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly (not always), distributionForInstance is used for regression studies whereas classifyInstance is used for classification studies. Of course distributionForInstance command can be used for classification but this requries a few line more code.

I strongly read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566505/7846405) and run this GitHub project [on your local environment](https://github.com/serengil/nn-weka/blob/master/nn/WekaSupervisedLearning.java).